# Coroutine Unit Testing Fails for the Class

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I am facing a weird issue while unit testing Coroutines. There are two tests on the class, when run individually, they both pass and when *I run the complete test class, one fails with assertion error*.
I am using `MainCoroutineRule` to use the `TestCoroutineScope` and relying on the latest Coroutine Testing Library
Here is the test :

```
    @Test
    fun testHomeIsLoadedWithShowsAndFavorites() {
        runBlocking {
            // Stubbing network and repository calls
            whenever(tvMazeApi.getCurrentSchedule("US", currentDate))
                .thenReturn(getFakeEpisodeList())
            whenever(favoriteShowsRepository.allFavoriteShowIds())
                .thenReturn(arrayListOf(1, 2))
        }

        mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
            // call home viewmodel
            homeViewModel.onScreenCreated()
            // Check if loader is shown
            assertThat(LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(homeViewModel.getHomeViewState())).isEqualTo(Loading)
            // Observe on home view state live data
            val homeViewState = LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(homeViewModel.getHomeViewState())
            // Check for success data
            assertThat(homeViewState is Success).isTrue()
            val homeViewData = (homeViewState as Success).homeViewData
            assertThat(homeViewData.episodes).isNotEmpty()
            // compare the response with fake list
            assertThat(homeViewData.episodes).hasSize(getFakeEpisodeList().size)
            // compare the data and also order
            assertThat(homeViewData.episodes).containsExactlyElementsIn(getFakeEpisodeViewDataList(true)).inOrder()
        }
    }
```

The other test is almost similar which tests for Shows without favorites. I am trying to test `HomeViewModel` method as:

```
        homeViewStateLiveData.value = Loading
        val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            onError(exception)
        }

        viewModelScope.launch(coroutineExceptionHandler) {
            // Get shows from network and favorites from room db on background thread
            val favoriteShowsWithFavorites = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val favoriteShowIds = favoriteShowsRepository.allFavoriteShowIds()
                val episodes = tvMazeApi.getCurrentSchedule(COUNTRY_US, currentDate)
                getShowsWithFavorites(episodes, favoriteShowIds)
            }
            // Return the combined result on main thread
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                onSuccess(favoriteShowsWithFavorites)
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot find the actual cause of why the tests if run separately are passing and when the complete class is tested, one of them is failing. Pls help if I am missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit and Room that come with Coroutine support owner the suspend functions and move them off the UI thread by their own. Thus, they reduce the hassles of handling thread callbacks by the developers in a big way. Initially, I was moving the suspend calls of network and DB to IO via `Dispatchers.IO` explicitly. This was unnecessary and also leading unwanted context-switching leading to flaky test. Since the libraries, automatically do it, it was just about handling the data back on UI when available.

```
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutineExceptionHandler) {
            // Get favorite shows from db, suspend function in room will launch a new coroutine with IO dispatcher
            val favoriteShowIds = favoriteShowsRepository.allFavoriteShowIds()
            // Get shows from network, suspend function in retrofit will launch a new coroutine with IO dispatcher
            val episodes = tvMazeApi.getCurrentSchedule(COUNTRY_US, currentDate)

            // Return the result on main thread via Dispatchers.Main
            homeViewStateLiveData.value = Success(HomeViewData(getShowsWithFavorites(episodes, favoriteShowIds)))
        }
```

Comment: can you link the doc which states that context switching are done internally in those library? It would really be appreciated.